# Should we be using the sha256 digest algorithm?

Tags: windows, code-signing, sha1, sha256

We are using a Digicert EV sha256 certificate to sign our code. However, we are using a sha1 "digest algorithm".

I've never really understood the implications of this but I do know that it gets around the "smart screen" warning that was presented for software that has been signed using sha1 after 1st Jan 2016. I assume that is because it knows we are using an EV certificate?

My main question is, should we be using a sha256 "digest algorithm" going forward (and a sha256 timestamp algorithm)? I see that sha1 is still quite common, having checked some of the applications on my PC.

Comment: recommendations is really off topic in SO.. you might want to rethink your question title

Comment: Maybe something for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks, I may try that but I'll leave it here just in case.